# Выравнивание компонентов в Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Не могу выровнять компоненты в `LinerLayout`. Нужно чтобы `imgButton` был справа, а `TextView` слева. В среде разработки все вроде правильно. Запускаю на телефоне, оно делит экран пополам (Вертикально) и некоторый текст не помещается. Вот код xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Вы где-то что-то проглядели. В приведённом коде ошибки нет. Создайте пустой проект, поместите в него эту разметку и она заработает. Сейчас у вас, видимо, ваша разметка в контейнере с `wrap_content` по ширине.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58949/discussion-on-question-by-fedia-cholak----layout).

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте:

1. Gravity imgButton - right, TextView - left.
2. Поместите imgButton и TextView в RelativeLayout
3. Поместите RelativeLayout в LinearLayout

Comment: третий пункт совершенно бессмысленный, что он по вашему должен дать?

Comment: Что бы елементы в LinearLayout располагались по всей размеренноси